# jasperreports cascading parameter not works

Tags: parameters, jasper-reports, jasperserver, cascading

I need one multi select parameter which get the values from db. I think cascading parameters are the correct thing to get this working?

I made a simple report to testing cascading parameters with jasperstudio 5.6.2 but the parameter is even empty. There is no data to select.

Here is the jrxml part:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_Landscape" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="e87dae0c-1038-441c-aa84-42d2224932d6">
    <parameter name="empl" class="java.util.Collection">
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[Select concat(last_name, ', ', first_name) AS name
FROM users
WHERE $X{IN, name, empl}
ORDER BY last_name, first_name]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="33" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="046a2154-24a7-4355-8677-3b300418f6ec"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="29" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="31dbb8be-03da-418b-8f93-cc86abdd7e03"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="19" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

What is wrong with this?
I have a cascading example report, but there is nothing different than here

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem:
Parameters should be defined in report and at server.
If you define at server you can choose that its values are got by database query, that is what I need. (you can also define the label for the parameter, that isn't possible in jasperstudio)
But cascading parameter aren't working till now.

best regards